# Выбрать главную метку: redirect/редирект/перенаправление/?

Tags: обсуждение, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки с одним смыслом:

- [redirect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) (83)
- [редирект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) (70)

Хорошо бы их синонимизировать, но какой вариант выбрать главным? «Редирект» — это калька, вроде не очень хорошо. Совсем не переводить? Перевести как для гуманитариев: [перенаправление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)?

Comment: «Редирект» как-то совсем не комильфо, либо «redirect», либо «перенаправление»

Comment: @VladD: согласен. А ещё вариант [tag:301-302]

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тогда уж 3xx. потому что статусов перенапровления сейчас уже девять (с 300 по 308): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection . а ведь перенаправления бывают не только в протоколе *http*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: охохо, сколько их развелось.

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю, что все эти теги необходимо **уничтожить**, добавив [http](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http) где его ещё нет.

- Тег **неоднозначен**: хотя в большинстве случаев разговор о редиректах/перенаправлениях касается HTTP, сам термин слишком общий.
- Тег **не добавляет контекста** в сочетании с тегами-соседями по вопросу, а в тексте вопроса есть всегда.
  Нужно настроить [apache](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) на правильную отдачу редиректов, или настроить какой-нибудь [wordpress](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), или редиректить мета-тегами из [html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), или речь о редиректах между [http](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http) и [https](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/https) в [nginx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx)? Или надо понять, как заставить [curl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) ходить по редиректам? Темы различаются довольно радикально, и мне сложно представить человека с кругозором, в который этот тег входит сколько-нибудь полно.
- В теге [redirect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect) подписчиков **нет**, в теге [редирект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82) есть **один**.

Comment: Радикальное решение! +1

Answer (score 1):

Ещё как вариант - переадресация.

Answer (score 0):

"redirect" или "редирект", но точно не "перенаправление".

Статистика вопросов по меткам показывает, что никто не станет использовать метку "перенаправление", а редиректы одинаково хороши.