# Ограничения на предложения и голосования по синонимам меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Здравствуйте. Захотел предложить синоним для метки [wamp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp) ► [wamp-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp-server). Оказалось, для предложения [необходимо](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA/info) иметь [2500 баллов репутации и рейтинг ответов по метке ≥ 5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/wamp/synonyms). Голосовать по утверждению синонима также возможно при достижении рейтинга ответов по метке ≥ 5.

Для чего столь высокий ценз? Понимаю, если бы он стоял на **утверждение** меток, но на **предложение** считаю неоправданно завышенным и тормозящим развитие Stack Overflow.

1. Синонимы утверждаются голосованием, т.е., если пользователь предложит неудачный, синоним заминусуют, и ничего страшного для проекта не произойдёт.
2. Как поступать с малоиспользуемыми метками? У метки [wamp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp) 8 вопросов, [наивысший рейтинг отвечающего по метке — 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/wamp/topusers). Следовательно, по правилам никто не сможет предложить синоним метки и проголосовать за него.

Comment: модераторы имеют право волевым решением утверждать синонимизировать и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy "волевым решением" звучит мощно. "Властью, данной мне общим голосованием участников, нарекаю вас Синонимом и Синонимом".

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну так и я об чем? :-D

Answer (score 5):

### Я сомневаюсь, что это синонимы.

*WAMP* это набор технологий сервера, так называемый **технологический стек**, состоящий из **W**indows, **A**pache, **M**ySQL и **P**HP.

*WampServer* это **дистрибутив** для быстрой установки вышеозначенного стека, снабжённый удобным установщиком и утилитой для управления. Строго говоря, стек WAMP можно установить и из отдельных кусочков, не используя WampServer.

По тегу можно заметить вопросы, где тег употреблён в разных значениях, *в основном по WampServer*.

Так что лично я считаю, что система совершенно права, что пока не даёт вам доступ к предложению синонимов. Но это всего лишь моё мнение по этому конкретному случаю.

---

У нас действуют пороги, обычные для сети StackExchange.

Когда ruSO был в **бете**, пороги репутации на привилегии были существенно снижены по сравнению с обычными. Выход из беты (аттестация) должнен служить индикацией того, что "полноценное сообщество образовалось", что оправдывает использование тех же порогов, что и везде.

Обобщение, конечно, далеко не всегда идеально работает, но здесь:

- Есть запасной план: **попросить модератора**, собрав доводы (модератор может не быть экспертом в этой области, убедите его, что это имеет смысл).
- *(Отвечая на другую часть вопроса)* **Вопросов там ещё совсем немного** (меньше десятка!), чтобы механизм синонимов был там необходим: в таких масштабах ещё можно отредактировать каждый вопрос, добавив туда подходящий тег, перевернув статистику использования тегов.

  В данном случае стоит добавить [wamp-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp-server) (**возможно**, заменив [wamp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp), где это уместно), и при вводе `wamp` система покажет, что по [wamp-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp-server) вопросов больше. Правда, это скорее *склонит* новичков правильно выбрать теги, лучше усилить этот эффект, *предложив **описания***. Решение, разумеется, исходит из **моего** предположения, что это **не** синонимы.

Comment: Да, определённо не синонимы, хотя близкие понятия. Вероятно, стоит дополнить описания меток, чтобы их не путали.

Comment: Спасибо, Павел, за как всегда вдумчивый и осторожный ответ. У меня не всегда так получается: вот сейчас совершил явную ошибку, что понятия синонимичны, испортив тем самым весь вопрос. Поверил [Гуглу](https://www.google.ru/search?q=filetype&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zR7yVsPdH8na6ASns7q4Cw#newwindow=1&q=wamp) и вопросам по метке [tag:wamp].

Comment: @СашаЧерных метки зарождаются стихийно и не всегда правильно. Поэтому чем метка "меньше", тем осторожнее надо к ней относиться. Пример нормальный, показательный.

Answer (score 3):

> Понимаю, если бы он стоял на утверждение меток, но на предложение считаю неоправданно завышенным и тормозящим развитие Stack Overflow

Как раз утверждение меток - менее ответственное действие. Предложение метки делается единолично, а для утверждения метки необходимо участие как минимум четверых участников.

2500 репутации - это признак того, что участник имеет достаточно опыта на сайте, понимает смысл и назначение меток.

> если пользователь предложит неудачный, синоним заминусуют

Практика голосования за закрытие вопросов показывает, что очень часто голосующие просто поддерживают уже имеющийся вариант, даже если он ошибочный. Особенно это касается дубликатов и путаницы между "уточнить подробности" и "конкретизировать". При голосовании за синонимы возможна та же ошибка. Поэтому первый голос (предложение синонима) наиболее важен.

Если у вас нет 2500 репутации, чтобы предложить синоним, а также если есть, но вы сомневаетесь в правильности решения, есть верный способ: инициировать обсуждение на Мете.

Если обсуждение покажет, что синонимизировать нужно, но голосующих участников недостаточно, то модератор может восполнить недостаток своим голосом. Но не вместо них и не минуя обсуждение.

Пример: обсудили, один из вариантов получил явную поддержку, приняли, объединили. [есть ли [исключения] для [exception]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2463/181472)

Пример 2: синонимизация не нужна, т.к. более уместно удаление неконкретных меток. [Выбрать главную метку: redirect/редирект/перенаправление/?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2457/181472)